# Magento PayPal Express incorrect country

Tags: paypal, paypal-express

We use the PayPal Express as a great way of letting customers checkout (via shopping cart shortcut). Everything is good, except that all the shipping address' countries are whatever our Merchant Country is (UK). So for example, a few minutes ago an order was placed in Germany. The Magento order confirmation show the country as being UK, but it should be Germany. The PayPal receipt has the same problem. But every single order outside the UK shows the UK as being the country, I doubt that it is a customer issue. How can this be fixed?

Comment: magento 1 or 2?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was never a response from the original author of the question.